# MS Access: Reports referencing other reports

Tags: ms-access

I have several MS Access 2010 Reports that contain controls that reference other controls on other Reports.  So, for example, if *report1* has a text box called *report1_textBox*, and this text box gets its value from a text box on *report0* called *report0_textBox*, then I set the **Control Source** property of *report1_textBox* to:

`= [Reports]![report0]![report0_textBox]`

I created a Form that the user can use to select Reports to open, and when the user selects a Report that depends on other Reports, my code opens those Reports before opening the selected Report.  This works fine in some instances, but in other instances I get some strange behavior.

Going back to the example above, I encounter situations where even if I open *report0*, then open *report1*, the text box *report1_textBox* displays **#Error** as if *report0* is closed or does not exist.  But if I then just click on *report0* and change its view then change it back, then go back to *report1* and scroll a little, the text box *report1_textBox* "magically" changes from **#Error** to the proper value.  I tried hitting the "Refresh All" button after opening the reports, and it does not update the text box.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this or at least work around it?

Thank you!

(*Adding*: Ideally, I do not want to open multiple reports like I'm doing now.  If the user wants to view a report, I would like to only open that report, but from what I understand, if the selected report needs data from another report, that other report needs to be open.  I can ultimately solve this by writing VBA code to execute queries, but I would like to avoid this, especially since I already have the data I need - it's just on another report.  Does anyone know if it is possible to realize this ideal situation?  Thanks!)

Comment: You have a design error -- no report should ever be dependent on data from another report. Get the data in some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest going with VBA code for this.

Your question, actually, contains an answer (partial) - if you need data from another report that report **must** be opened first. However, the following code might help you somewhat.
You can open report(s) as hidden:

```
...
DoCmd.OpenReport "report0", acViewReport, , , acHidden
...
```

But again, I would recommend to write VBA code to pull the data using either existing queries from other reports or create new ones [queries].